# getCustomerGroupId returns 0

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

In my other post, I follow steps to be able to pull the Customer Group of a certain customer inside invoice module.

I created this file
**app/design/frontend/default/default/template/pdf/statement.phtml**

Then in my PDF I edited the HTML and place this one

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='pdf/statement.phtml'}}
```

Then I have this code

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
echo $groupId;    // this one returns 0 so it always redirects to ICT
die();
if ($groupId == 10)
{
    echo $this->__('CGD');
} else {
   echo $this->__('ICT');
}
```

Where did I go wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you get `0` because your customer is not logged in, go to admin->Customer->Customer group->then you will find `0 => NOT LOGGED IN` this is why you get it.

Try to logged in and then look your piece of code, you will output `1` for exemple if your customer group is `General`.

Comment: @ PFlorentino please accept the answer IF it has been helpful